# How to create a toggle/radio item in the menu/toolbar of an Eclipse e4 application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

What is the canonical way of creating a menu item that implements a toggle or radio state in an eclipse e4 rcp application?

It seems such a basic thing, but all the documentation I found relies on e3 API and creates dependencies to org.eclipse.ui, which is not allowed in e4.

Comment: A menu where? For parts in the Application or fragment e4xmi file you just add the appropriate menu items to the menu in the e4xmi. The Vogella tutorial covers menus [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#exercise-adding-menus)

Comment: Anywhere. 
The problem is not adding the menu item. The problem is the state associated with it.

Comment: @greg-449
I want e.g. a menu item "toggle off", the user clicks it, then the handler executes and the item says "toggle on". Or instead of changing the label there could be a checkmark.

Or for example a radio group with radio items A, B, C:
The user should be able to select one of the items of the radio group. And this selection should be saved in a state associated with the items.

Comment: It is up to you to save the state somewhere, e4 doesn't provide anything. You can get the selected state of the individual menu items from the `MItem` but that is it.

Comment: @greg-449
That's my question. How do I associate state information with a menu item and how do I retrieve it. Is there any documentation? Or could you provide a barebones example?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Radio_Button_Command
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Toggle_Button_Command

This describes the way you do it in e3. I'm looking for a e4 equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way that I use for a radio button menu which saves the radio button state in the part class.

I use multiple `Direct Menu Item` entries with the type set to `Radio`.

I set a Tag value (on the supplementary page of the menu item) to the value I want to associate with the menu item.

I use the same handler for all of the menu items.

In the handler I inject the `MPart` and the `MItem`:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(final MPart part, final MItem mitem)
{
  // Only take action on the selected radio item

  if (!mitem.isSelected())
    return;

  // The tag value specifying the radio state

  String tag = mitem.getTags().get(0);

  // Get the part class

  MyPart myPart = (MyPart)part.getObject();

  // tell the part about the state change

  myPart.setState(tag);
}
```

Instead of the `MPart` you could also use any class that is in the Eclipse Context - such as one declared as `@Creatable` and `@Singleton`.